# React wrong result on the change of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-context

I'm new to react and working on simple eCommerce application. I am changing the quantity of  in the cart when it is added more than one times but it gives wrong result(As we can see in the output the 'quantity' I print and in the object are different eg. before:**1** after:**2** but in the object it is **3**).I'll appreciate any help. Thank You!!

here is my reducer.js

```
export const initialState = {
    basket : [],

}


const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "ADD_TO_BASKET":
            const newIndex = state.basket.findIndex((basketItem)=> basketItem.id==action.item.id)
            if(newIndex >= 0){
                const newBasket = [...state.basket];
                console.log(newBasket);
                console.log("quantity "+newBasket[newIndex].quantity);
                newBasket[newIndex].quantity+=action.item.quantity;
                console.log(newBasket);
                console.log("quantity "+newBasket[newIndex].quantity);
                return{
                    ...state,
                    basket: [...newBasket]
                }
            }
            return{
                ...state,
                basket: [...state.basket ,action.item]
            }
            .
            .
            .

export default reducer;
```

here is my checkout.js:

```
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider"
function Checkout() {
    const [{basket}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
return (
        <div className='checkout'>
            <div className="checkout__left">
                <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/02/UK_CCMP/TM/OCC_Amazon1._CB423492668_.jpg" alt="" className="checkout__ad" />
                <div>
                    <h2 className='checkout__title'>
                        Your Shopping Basket
                    </h2>
                    {basket.map(item => (
                        // console.log("checkout product quantity: "+JSON.stringify(item.quantity)),
                        <CheckoutProduct 
                            key={i++}
                            id = {item.id}
                            title = {item.title}
                            image = {item.image}
                            price = {item.price}
                            rating = {item.rating}
                            quantity = {item.quantity}
                        />
                    ))}
 .
 .
 .
```

StateProvider.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react'

//prepares the data layer
export const StateContext = createContext();

//wrap our app and provide the data layer
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);

//pull infromation from the data layer
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Output in console:

```
-> [{…}]0: {---, quantity: 3}length: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
-> quantity 1
->[{…}]0: {---, quantity: 3}---
-> quantity 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove React.StrictMode wrapper in index.js file.
The Strict mode is done by intentionally double-invoking some functions.

Comment: Thank you very much:) It worked, I don't know why though! But I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you tell me how to stop the cart(data of my state) getting erased every time I reload the page??